# Getting version mismatch error on ng serve

Tags: angular

When doing ng Serve I am getting an error like this

```
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /home/abhishek/projects/themeBootstrap4/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts,
 found version 4, expected 3,resolving symbol DashboardModule in /home/abhishek/projects/themeBootstrap4/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts, 
resolving symbol DashboardModule in /home/abhishek/projects/themeBootstrap4/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts
```

Can anyone tell me why it is coming or how can I resolve it

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LineChartComponent } from './line-chart/line-chart.component';
import { BarChartComponent } from './bar-chart/bar-chart.component';
import {MatCheckboxModule,MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';
export const routes = [
  {path:'',component:DashboardComponent},

 ] 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent, LineChartComponent, BarChartComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

This is my dashboard module

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send your package.json. If you install angular material on your existing project with Angular 4 you will have version miss match. Angular material is version 5.0.0-rc0. You should upgrade your angular to version 5 here is [guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) for that

```
npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'

npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
```

Comment: Thanks it soved my problem

Comment: I’m happy to help :)